# count the number of integers in an array

Tags: numpy, scipy

I'm sure this is a really simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer. How can I get a count on the number of integers in a numpy array? I suspect there is a built-in count() method? Here is an example of what I am looking for:

`>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`
`>>> numpy.count(x)`
`5`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

size provides the number of elements in an array. e.g. `x.size`

Comment: many thanks. i have no clue how i forgot this... i'll just chalk it up to friday!